# How to sort a data frame following an "IF" analysis in Python

Tags: python, anaconda, jupyter-notebook

I have a data frame:

```
q4raw = records[['Agency Name', 'Cardholder Last Name', 'Cardholder First Initial', 'Amount', 'Vendor', 'Transaction Date']]
```

And I want to sort the data according to the following request:

"Display all transaction details where the vendor and purchaser are the same on a specific day, there is more than one transaction for the day and the combined total of the transaction was more than $5,000. Sort them in ascending order by the TransactionDate."

What shall I do? I tried grouping data by 'Transaction Date', 'Vendor', and then 'Customer', and count how many transactions a customer has completed with the same vendor on the same date, but I am having trouble trying to only keep the data that follows the scenario described.

Answer (score 0):

I assume your data struct is a list

```
q4raw = [['Agency Name', 'Cardholder Last Name', 'Cardholder First Initial', 'Amount', 'Vendor', 'Transaction Date']]
sorted(q4raw, key=operator.itemgetter(5))
```

Comment: Yes, it is a list extracted from an excel worksheet.